# Is it possible to reference another field than the id field in messages and titles?

Tags: react-admin

I would like the titles of the screens, as well as the delete confirmation messages, to use a different field to identify the record to the user than the id, since the id format is not very human friendly.

I know how to customise the text of the messages and titles. However, I have no idea how to access other fields than the id param when constructing the text message.

Is this possible, or do I need to anonymise the messages to not include a reference to the actual record?

[This is an illustration of the delete message, where I'd like something nicer for the user, like eg. the e-mail of the employee to delete, instead of the random string that is the id value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bywDc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page headers you can use any field from the record:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Show.html#page-title

```
const PostTitle = ({ record }) => {
    return <span>Post {record ? `"${record.title}"` : ''}</span>;
};

export const PostShow = (props) => (
    <Show title={<PostTitle />} {...props}>
        ...
    </Show>
);
```

In the deletion confirmation dialog, now it is impossible to change the id field to another, in my opinion this possibility is only in development: 
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/DeleteWithConfirmButton.js

Comment: You can probably replace the components: DeleteButton / DeleteWithConfirmButton with your own.

Comment: If it's only the dialogs, I might just override the message in the dictionary with a message that does not include the id. As long as I only do delete's from a show or edit screen, this should give enough context. This does mean I won't be able to use the delete button on the ListItem, since I like to avoid misclicks, which is easy in a List view.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for how to do this with `DeleteWithConfirmButton`, here's how you could do it:

```
interface CustomDeleteWithConfirmationProps
  extends DeleteWithConfirmButtonProps {
  field?: string;
}

export default function CustomDeleteWithConfirmation({
  field,
  confirmTitle,
  ...rest
}: CustomDeleteWithConfirmationProps) {
  const record = useRecordContext();

  return (
    <DeleteWithConfirmButton
      confirmTitle={
        field ? `Delete ${record[field]}?` : confirmTitle
      }
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}
```